# pytorch inplace runtime error with class inheritance

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autograd

May I know why [this forward() function](https://gist.github.com/buttercutter/b6f526c56e20f029d68e6f9041c3f5c0/405c55d8ccfa1dbaa9be0a6982cd43fa0fd6dc7f#file-gdas-py-L396) gives [runtime error](https://gist.github.com/buttercutter/b6f526c56e20f029d68e6f9041c3f5c0/405c55d8ccfa1dbaa9be0a6982cd43fa0fd6dc7f#file-runtime-log) on **inplace** operation ?

Note: I have done some code debugging which leads to the following line of code:

```
class ConvEdge(Edge):    
    def __init__(self, stride): 
        super().__init__()        
        self.f = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(stride, stride), padding=1)
```

If you guys have a look at the code snippet regarding `class ConvEdge(Edge)` , I am actually having second thought on how ***inheritance*** is being viewed and processed by pytorch autograd library.

What do you guys think ?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example that leads to this kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is resolved using [with torch.no_grad()](https://github.com/buttercutter/gdas/commit/94bffd1388223a79061a86a622c79c0ccac2b222) which basically does not propagate the gradient when it is not necessary.